# Magento 2.2.6 - Cybersource official integration module issue

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I'm facing the following issue with official Cybersource integration module downloaded from the Magento Marketplace.

```
`PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getStoreId() on null in /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Payment.php:286
Stack trace:
#0 /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Payment.php(180): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment->getMethodInstance()
#1 /vendor/cybersource/module-secure-acceptance/Controller/Index/PlaceOrder.php(144): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment->importData(Object(Magento\Framework\DataObject))
#2 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): CyberSource\SecureAcceptance\Controller\Index\PlaceOrder->execute()
#3 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): CyberSource\SecureAcceptance\Co in /vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Payment.php on line 286`
```

Comment: Hi, Did you get a solution?

Comment: i'm having same issue?